# asp.net pdf linking; page number not matching

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

a client would like the ability to link to pdf pages. Linking to the PDF works fine, but my problem is that in, specifically Chrome, (and possibly other browsers) it links to a page number that is not equal to the number given in the url.
Here is an example:

```
text.Text += "<br><a href='/Resources/mypdf.pdf#page=" + 12 + "'>View Example (Page " + 12 + ")</a>;
```

This will add a link to the text field, which I am able to click, but it will send me to page 13 instead of 12.
Is there anything I can do to fix this issue with Chrome's pdf display? I was considering having something to check what browser is being used, and set the number to be 1 less if it is chrome, but I am unsure of how, or if that would even be a good idea.

Comment: do you have an example that we can check in the other browsers?

Comment: did you find the answer to your question? please post the answer if it isn't listed, and accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

you need to subtract one from the number that you want.

the array starts at 0.

have you checked this in all the other browsers?  Internet Explorer might be the only one that doesn't do it like this,  but I am thinking that it is in the way that the PDF Viewer works and not the browser.

**Update**

subtract 1 from the page number you want.  that is how the pdf viewer is set up, pretty sure that there are going to be a lot of them like that.  if that is the most common pdf Viewer then that should be your standard.

**Checking for Browser**

here is a page that runs through a JavaScript to find the Browser that the user is using.  you will probably have to adapt it so that you can change your link based on what browser is being used.

[Browser Detect in Javascript](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are correct that it is the PDF Viewer and not the browser. But knowing this does little to help me, because I still need to find a way to determine if the link should include the actual page number, or one less than page intended.

Comment: that is what you need to do. subtract 1 from the page number you want.  that is how the pdf viewer is set up, pretty sure that there are going to be a lot of them like that.  if that is the most common pdf Viewer then that should be your standard.

Comment: I see what you mean, you are saying most browsers will use the number as intended, and only a few will not... This will cause IE to link to a page less than we wanted, do you know of a way to see the browser is IE and set the number += 1 ?

Comment: Have you tested this?  do you know that there are some Browsers that will cause issues? I don't think it has anything to do with the Browser, I think it has to do with the pdf Viewer, the url is sending instructions to the pdf viewer to tell it which page to go to, so the instructions will be read by the pdf viewer and interpreted by the PDF Viewer.  **as always, Test it in all the browsers you are concerned about**

Comment: I have tested in all browsers that I am concerned about, and only chrome is the one going to a page less than the intended page. I have read that chrome (unlike the other browsers) has its own pdf viewer, which is why it shows one page higher than the other browsers. With this in mind, how can I detect what browser is being used, so that I can send separate instructions for chrome?

Comment: I am not very fluent in Javascript but the site I mentioned in my answer looks like it will be able to help you a ton with what you are trying to accomplish